# How to set page title tag in custom template for non-Custom Post Type?

Tags: templates, metabox, wp-title

I have this code in my custom template file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: custom-template-view
*/
ob_start();
get_header();


function assignPageTitle(){
  return "my page title";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');// not working
add_filter('the_title', 'assignPageTitle'); // not working


?>

<div>MY CONTENT</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I want to set custom title tag but it is not working.
In this template I am showing records from custom table.

Comment: Did you try `<?php the_title();?>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template files are not the right place to add in functions like that. The template file isnt loaded until late in the hook/filter process. Your function should be in functions.php. This way it can be added in before your tempalte files load, and functions that are in use in them can be altered.

Often times `wp_title()` is used in the header.php so it possible you are using that, but form the code you show you are filtering functions you are not using. Except maybe in header.php, but its loaded and executed before this custom template file. You also do not show the use of `the_title()` so I can not tell how/when/where this would actually filter anything if the function was placed in the right location.

Comment: I am trying to do the same - I get what you are saying but I am now trying right at the end of functions file to set the title of my dynamic page..alas the title is still 404 ing..thats what I want to overide in certain cases - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252825/where-is-the-best-part-to-hijack-or-catch-a-potential-404/252826#252826

Comment: I have responded to your question on your post. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253188/10907

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just echo you custom post title? For example:

```
if (some_conditional) {
    echo 'My custom title';
} else {
    the_title();
}
```