# Where is the best part to hijack or catch a potential 404

Tags: 404-error

I would like to know the best part of the code to catch a 404 that doesn't match a template.
However at this point I will check for the url string and output my own dynamic html if it matches a pattern. It is DYNAMIC content because there is no content in the wordpress backend for it. So I am looking to echo html and exit if it matches. If not then continue and 404 as normal.

In reference to this question too.
[Dynamic URL generates dynamic content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252289/dynamic-url-generates-dynamic-content/252293)

TY

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to catch a non–match to template in WP because it will *always* match *some* template. The very last template it will fall back to will simply be `index.php`, the most generic one in template hierarchy.

In general the appropriate hook for such logic is typically `template_redirect` in `template-loader.php`. At this point the query is done, the conditional context is fully set up, but native template resolution and inclusion hadn't fired yet.

Comment: Ok then I mean catch a 404 for a non existent slug (therfore url) - so a 404 would be about to happen. Thanks for your advice I will checkout the template-loader file.

Comment: So I now have everything working except that the server is returning a 404 page (as in effect wordpress sees it like that)..will try and force a normal header..somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [404.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) file. That is a normal file to have as part of your theme. You can handle all of your logic in there and have it load your dynamic html in it.

**OR**

You can use a function like the following in your functions.php file. I just tested and you can get most of what you need from the URL using the `var_dump()` placed in this function.

```
// borrowed from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1883/10907
function stoi2m1_404_override() {
    global $wp_query;

    // return if not a 404 page
    if (!$wp_query->is_404)
        return;

    // dump the data in the query, parameters from the URL
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($wp_query->query);
    echo '</pre>';

    /* resulted in something like this for me, Im using a custom post type movies
    array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["movies"]=>
        string(4) "missing"
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(6) "movies"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "missing"
    }*/

    if ($wp_query->query['name'] == 'missing' ) { //what ever name/title of post you are looking for
        status_header( 200 ); // set the appropriate header
        $wp_query->is_404=false; // set is_404 to false

        // apply any more logic you need here
        // or include custom template file here
        // you will want to keep the usual template from loading   
    }
}
add_filter('template_redirect', 'stoi2m1_404_override' );
```